How to use GitHub Actions Runner Images in a self hosted runner?
I have set up a self hosted github actions runner based on this image: ghcr.io/actions/actions-runner:latest.
It does seem that the Github Actions hosted runners are using pretty much the same image, but they do something else with it to include all the software from this repository: https://github.com/actions/runner-images
I did not manage to find out how they do this or find ready docker images to use.
Is it possible to somehow reuse them fully, and not only the "base" image?

I suggest reading this section in the runner-images repository you shared.

I was hoping there exist something simpler, rather a docker that I can use, or some script to get it into my image from the released versions of github runner images

For being a part of their business offer, I can understand why they don't want to make it easy to reproduce.

This is essentially a docker/container image whereas the public repository contains code for the Azure VM images.
github-hosted runners execute the workflows in virtual machines hosted in Azure.
If you intend to use the same VM images repository, then you need to set the VM infrastructure in Azure and deploy your VM with images generated from the repository.
However, for containerized self-hosted runner you need to create your own docker images, the public github runner images repository can only provide you with the software that you may intend to install in your image.
